# In Sublime how to remove all text after the final reference to a specific character?

Tags: sublimetext3

I know this is do-able in sublime but I don't know how:

I have a text list with each line looking like this:

```
/examplefolder1/examplefolder2/file.txt
/asdfsf/sdfsdf/fsdfsdf/file2.txt
file3.txt
```

I want to remove everything before the last "/" of each line so that it becomes:

```
file.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

How can I do this in Sublime?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find: `^.*/`
- Replace: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
.*      # 0 or more any character
/       # a slash
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]